# Mediasoup routing among pods

Tags: webrtc, mediasoup

Regarding routing of media streams among pods

Suppose in my kubernetes cluster, i have two mediasoup pods A and B for handling mediastream.It is group video calling.
If in the same room,5 participants are connected to pod A and 5 participants are connected to pod B , how can i send mediastream of each participant in pod A as well as to pod B to send to others peers?